# How To Drag the UIView from one parent to another parent using Long press gesture in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Is this possible to drag the UIView from one parent to another parent by using Long press gesture. I have tried the below code snippet but am not able to achieve my solution,

```
private void LongPressGestureUpdated(UILongPressGestureRecognizer longPressGesture)
{
            if (longPressGesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
            {
                // Start to Drag view
            }
            if (longPressGesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed)
            {
                // Drag view based on moving point location
            }
            if (longPressGesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
            {
                // Drop the view
            }
        }
```

In above code snippet when i move the uiview along with finger **UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed** was called, so when we drag the view to next parent the uiview should be visible on parent view. But this view was not visible.

Please anyone suggest how can i achieve this behaviour.

Comment: The easiest way to implement drag/drop between containers/views is to implement `UIDragInteraction` and `UIDropInteraction` delegates and enable interaction (`UserInteractionEnabled`) on the views you wish to be draggable and you avoid all the manual gesture code, moving of the views, accepting/snapping in the drop location, etc..

Comment: @SushiHangover, Thanks for the answer, UIDragInteraction and UIDropInteraction delegate API available in iOS version 11.0 and not below version, I have found the alternate solution for my problem. Thanks for the help.